# How to remove duplicate element based on combination of multiple attributes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is how my Input XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Account  InceptionDate="03/01/2005"  BusinessWorkGroup="US" BusinessUnit="BOS" AccountId="XYZ4321" ISOCurrency="USD" DomicileCountry="USA">
<AssignContact ContactId="123" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="123" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="123" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
</Account>  
<Account  InceptionDate="03/01/2006"  BusinessWorkGroup="US" BusinessUnit="BOS" AccountId="ABC1231" ISOCurrency="USD" DomicileCountry="USA">
<AssignContact ContactId="543" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="543" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="211" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
</Account>  
<Account  InceptionDate="03/01/2010"  BusinessWorkGroup="US" BusinessUnit="BOS" AccountId="DUM111" ISOCurrency="USD" DomicileCountry="USA">
<AssignContact ContactId="987" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="987" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="211" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
</Account> 
</root>
```

My output should look like:  (For each AccountId - Duplicate [combination of ContactId & Type ] should be removed from final xml ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Account  InceptionDate="03/01/2005"  BusinessWorkGroup="US" BusinessUnit="BOS" AccountId="XYZ4321" ISOCurrency="USD" DomicileCountry="USA">
<AssignContact ContactId="123" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="123" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
</Account>  
<Account  InceptionDate="03/01/2006"  BusinessWorkGroup="US" BusinessUnit="BOS" AccountId="ABC1231" ISOCurrency="USD" DomicileCountry="USA">
<AssignContact ContactId="543" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="543" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="211" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
</Account>
<Account  InceptionDate="03/01/2010"  BusinessWorkGroup="US" BusinessUnit="BOS" AccountId="DUM111" ISOCurrency="USD" DomicileCountry="USA">
<AssignContact ContactId="987" Type="Administrative Assistant"/>
<AssignContact ContactId="211" Type="Portfolio Manager"/>
</Account> 
</root>
```

XSLT I am using which is not working properly, please let me  know how can I modify my xsl so that it also look for Type along with ContactId

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AssignContact">
    <xsl:if test="not(@ContactId=preceding-sibling::AssignContact/@ContactId)">
      <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do a search for XSLT grouping.

Comment: At this point you don't have anything I could help you with. Do some homework first.

Comment: Please see my sample XSL

Comment: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Hi @Dimitre Novatchev I need your inputs

Comment: You cannot ping someone that was not previously involved in the post, so Dimitre will not be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided in comments was for a technique called "Muenchian Grouping". In your case you want to group `AssignContact` by their parent `AccountId` and their `ContactId` and `TypeId` attributes. This means using an concatenated key.

```
<xsl:key name="Contact" 
         match="AssignContact" 
         use="concat(../@AccountId, '|', @ContactId, '|', @Type)" />
```

Notice how you don't have to give the full path to `AssignContact` here. Also note the use of the `|` pipe character to separate the arguments. You can use any character here, just as long as it doesn't appear in any of the strings you are concatenating.

The next thing to mention, is because you are using the identity template here, you shouldn't need to worry about copying existing nodes in other templates. You only need to write templates from nodes you wish to remove. In your case, you wish to remove `AssignContact` nodes where the combination `AccountId`,  `ContactId` and `TypeId` attributes have already occurred. Using Muenchian Grouping, the expression looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="AssignContact
                     [generate-id() != generate-id(key('Contact', concat(../@AccountId, '|', @ContactId, '|', @Type))[1])]" />
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="Contact" match="AssignContact" use="concat(@ContactId, '|', @Type)" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AssignContact[generate-id() != generate-id(key('Contact', concat(../@AccountId, '|', @ContactId, '|', @Type))[1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This xslt also removing the <AssignContact ContactId="211" Type="Portfolio Manager"/> from the AccountId="DUM111", I need to remove duplicates for one AccountID

Comment: I've amended my answer to fix this. For future reference, please can you make sure you mention the requirements clearly in your question, because at the moment you question says `Duplicate [combination of ContactId & Type]` which is why I missed it. Thank you!